# Remove All Elements from a GridY zone

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am trying to create a program that sets JLabels, use the GridBagLayout.

I want to create a button that when pressed removes everything from a certain gridY location. How do I do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. When you add these components to their parent container keep them in a structure (maybe a List). Something like:

```
    JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    //...
    List<Component> components = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add components to container and to list...
    for (Component c : components) {
        container.remove(c);
    }
    container.revalidate();
    container.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Container` class has a method `getLayout()`. This will allow you to get the `GridBagLayout` instance for your panel.
2. The `Container` class also has a method `getComponents()`

So once you get all the components in an array you iterate through the array. For each component you would:

1. Use the `getConstraints()` method of the `GridBagLayout`.
2. Then check the `gridy` value of the `GridBagConstraints` object to see what row the component is in.
3. Remove the component from the panel if it meets your criteria.

After the loop is finished you invoke `revalidate()` on the panel.